# Update query with order by

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-order-by

I am trying to update one column based on another column short. I am using `order by`, but while using `select top(10000)` my incremental number going 4000 series but I need from 101, but initially I `declare int 100`

```
DECLARE @IncrementValue int
SET @IncrementValue = 100

UPDATE CabecDoc 
SET CDU_NumberBook = @IncrementValue,
    @IncrementValue = @IncrementValue + 1 
FROM
    (SELECT TOP(7000) *
     FROM CabecDoc
     WHERE data BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-07-17'
       AND Entidade = 'VD4' 
       AND tipodoc = 'VD' AND CDU_SimbolBook = '*'
     ORDER BY NumDoc ASC) CabecDoc
```

I need update column from 101 to an incremental number through 7000 records.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need. No need to declare variables.

```
UPDATE
  CabecDoc
SET
  CDU_NumberBook = 100 + RowNum
FROM
  (
    Select
      top(7000) *,  
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        ORDER BY
          NumDoc
      ) AS RowNum
    FROM
      CabecDoc
    WHERE
      data between '2019-05-01'
      and '2019-07-17'
      and Entidade = 'VD4'
      and tipodoc = 'VD'
      and CDU_SimbolBook = '*'
    ORDER BY
      RowNum ASC
  ) CabecDoc
```